# What is difference between B2BUA and PBX?

Tags: c#, sip, voip, rtp

I am starting to develop client-server VoIP application and going to use ozeki.voip.sip library from nuget (http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com). When I stated to study SIP, I knew about [B2BUA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-to-back_user_agent) (back 2 back user agent), I decided it will be will be good variant for server in my app.

Later, when I was looking for SIP RTP library, I learned about PBX (Private Branch eXchange), ozeki often uses this term in their tutorials, and this term is not clear for me.

Is it the same thing as B2BUA? And, if someone knows, if they are not the same, what will be better for server in my application? It will multiuser app with one-to-one calls, group calls and chats in both cases. User registration is also planed.

Comment: PBX is an old term that considerably predates VoIP, it refers to the local telephony network.  As opposed to the telephone company's network.  When you call a team member inside your company's office building then you typically dial a 3 or 4 digit number, its PBX makes the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its the same, but I think you mean IP-PBX instead of PBX. PBX is IP-PBX without VoiP.

On this site: [Orbtalk](https://www.orbtalk.co.uk/blog/cloud-pbx-and-sip-trunk-whats-the-difference) is a good explaination of the difference between a Cloud PBX and a SIP Trunk. And in this explaination stands the following:

> Since an IP PBX is a Back-To-Back User Agent (B2BUA) and not a mere SIP Proxy, it is able to provide a range of really useful additional features over a standard SIP trunk.

I'm not a specialist in this topic. Perhaps others users can help, if their mean I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The PBX is a Phone System, traditional PBX usually is a hardware, now the popular PBX is  software based which using the SIP protocol.

The B2BUA is mean architecture.

A PBX could be B2BUA architecture, or proxy architecture. the B2BUA architecture PBX is base on the dialog level, the proxy architecture PBX is transaction level based.

So far to my knowledge, the B2BUA architecture PBX is contested most seats.